# Understanding the computation of a determinant in the framework of exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, determinant

Given a vector space $V$ with a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, an inner product on $V$ is given by
$$
\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=g^{ij}
$$
Furthermore, there is an inner product on $V\otimes V$, given by
$$
\langle e_i\otimes e_j,e_k\otimes e_l\rangle=g^{ik}g^{jl}
$$
Repeat this process we can obtain an inner product on $\bigoplus^kV$.

Then I want to show
$$
\frac{1}{k!}\langle e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k},e_{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{j_k}\rangle=\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
g^{i_1 j_1} & \cdots & g^{i_1 j_k} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
g^{i_k j_1} & \cdots & g^{i_k j_k}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $e_1\wedge e_2=e_1\otimes e_2-e_2\otimes e_1$ and so on.

Here I compute the case $k=2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac12\langle e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2},e_{j_1}\wedge e_{j_2}\rangle&=\frac12\langle e_{i_1}\otimes e_{i_2}-e_{i_2}\otimes e_{i_1},e_{j_1}\otimes e_{j_2}- e_{j_2}\otimes e_{j_1}\rangle\\
&=\frac12(g^{i_1j_1}g^{i_2j_2}-g^{i_1j_2}g^{i_2j_1}-g^{i_2j_1}g^{i_1j_2}+g^{i_2j_2}g^{i_1j_1})\\
&=(g^{i_1j_1}g^{i_2j_2}-g^{i_1j_2}g^{i_2j_1})\\
&=\operatorname{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
g^{i_1j_1}& g^{i_1j_2}\\
g^{i_2j_1}& g^{i_2j_2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Is there a method to compute arbitrary $k$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry but your title isn't a good one. 1) "rough" should be "tough" 2) But saying that in fact "tough" isn't informative (a "tough problem" for someone is easy for another one). Your title should be changed into something like "Understanding the computation of a determinant in the framework of exterior algebra"

Comment: Are you sure that your definition is correct? I have a doubt: if $\{e_1\ldots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis then $g^{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$. Thus, for $i\neq j$, $\|e_i\otimes e_j\|^2 = (g^{ij})^2 = 0$ although $e_i\otimes e_j \neq 0$. Hence, the formula you gave do not give an inner product on $V\otimes V$.
Moreover, it seems that your iterated process only gives "inner products" (that are not inner products) on $V^{\otimes 2^k}$ for some $k$, not on all tensor powers of $V$ .

Comment: @Didier In that case $\|e_i\otimes e_j\|^2=\langle e_i\otimes e_j,e_i\otimes e_j\rangle=\langle e_i,e_i\rangle\langle e_j,e_j\rangle=1$.

Comment: @blargoner Oh right! I have mistaken the order of the indexes. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition
$$e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}(-1)^{\sigma}e_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_{\sigma(k)}}$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
\langle e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k},e_{j_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{j_k}\rangle&=\sum_{\sigma,\tau}(-1)^{\sigma}(-1)^{\tau}\langle e_{i_{\sigma(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_{\sigma(k)}},e_{j_{\tau(1)}}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{j_{\tau(k)}}\rangle\\
&=\sum_{\sigma,\tau}(-1)^{\sigma}(-1)^{\tau}g^{i_{\sigma(1)}j_{\tau(1)}}\cdots g^{i_{\sigma(k)}j_{\tau(k)}}\\
&=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{\tau}(-1)^{\sigma\tau^{-1}}g^{i_{\sigma\tau^{-1}(1)}j_1}\cdots g^{i_{\sigma\tau^{-1}(k)}j_k}\\
&=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{\rho}(-1)^{\rho}g^{i_{\rho(1)}j_1}\cdots g^{i_{\rho(k)}j_k}\\
&=\sum_{\sigma}\det(g^{i_p j_q})\\
&=k!\det(g^{i_p j_q})
\end{align*}$$